# Group Policy applied OU but not applying to computers in security filtering group

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I'm having issues with getting my GPO to be pushed out.

Here are the steps that I took.

I created an OU (Workstation OU), in that Workstation OU, I put a Security group (SG-Workstation), and in that security group is a list of all the computers that need to have the GPO applied to.

I configured the GPO (The GPO only has computer configurations, no user configuration) and attached the GPO to the Workstation OU, link enabled and enforced. And changed the security filtering to have the Workstation OU only.

I ran gpupdate /force on both client and server. And checked gpresult to see if I was getting the group policy, and nothing. I rebooted, to see if would get the policy then, and still nothing.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3163622/ms16-072-security-update-for-group-policy-june-14--2016

Comment: Thanks for the link, I changed the security filtering to only include Domain Computers but it still was not successful.

Comment: If it doesn't reveal too much, a screenshot of the ADUC, and policy might help us see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link the GPO to the OU that contains the workstations. Based on your question, it sounds like the actual computer objects may be in a different OU.

As an aside, it is generally advised to not use the "Enforced" option except in advanced use cases. The GPO will be applied as long as "Enabled" is...enabled.

Comment: Good catch. I missed that in the question. The computer accounts need to be in the OU that the GPO is linked to.

Comment: That works. I was trying to assign it to a separate OU that has an SG with all the computers in it so I wouldn't have to move any of the machines out of their current OU's or deploy the same GPO on multiple OU's. Thanks

Comment: You can still apply the gpo to multiple OUs and use security filtering with that group so it doesn't only applies to specific computers.